# what is difference between View controller and class

Tags: ios, objective-c, class, uiviewcontroller

### This Is my class.h

```
#import "BankAccountDetails.h"
    static int openAccounts = 0;
    @implementation BankAccountDetails

    +(BankAccountDetails *) newAlloc{
        openAccounts++;

        return [BankAccountDetails alloc];
    }
    +(int) totalOpen{
         return openAccounts;;
    }
```

### And This Is my ViewController.h

```
 #import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize lbl;

- (void)loadView{
    [super loadView];
    NSLog(@" 1 LoadView Calling");
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    lbl=[[UILabel alloc] init];
    lbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    lbl.text = @"hello frnd i'm making a lable ";
    [self.view addSubview:lbl];
```

Please see this Question carefully and My Question is , Actually i m confuse I want to know Difference Between  Class.h and controller.h While both are Class.

Comment: Some one Help  Actually i have Same Problem

Comment: A view controller is a special case of a class, one that inherits from UIViewController and which is responsible for managing some subclass of UIView.  A view controller is thus a class, but a class is not necessarily a view controller.

Comment: (Hopefully your ViewController.h file defines ViewController as inheriting from UIViewController or one of its subclasses.)

Comment: it will help you https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/DefiningClasses/DefiningClasses.html

Comment: Your code will throw errors because you have put code that is part of the implementation file `.m` into your header file `.h`. I think you really need to go back and read the basics before you continue any further.

Comment: @Popeye - Not true.  The `@interface` above is a private class extension and is "completely normal" (though certainly confusing) by the latest standards.  (Except I now see that the file is erroneously named "ViewController.h" vs "ViewController.m".)

Comment: @HotLicks I suspect it is just a typo and they meant `.m` but you never know these days I have mentioned it before and a user told me I was wrong and the `.h` files were the implementation files and I ended up leaving the conversation.

Answer (score 1):

Class is an abstract word which is used by people like us (Programmers) to make represent real entities into a digital world.

So that all views, objects and controllers can be common called as Class.

So view controller is a type of class which is a controller for a view to manage view and its subview and related actions on it.

The main difference in your both class is both have different methods.

I mean `class.h` has class methods. Class methods are the methods which can called with out creating object of the class. You can simply call it by using just class name.

For example:

```
int total = [BankAccountDetails totalOpen];
```

And `ViewController.h` class contains instance method, to call these methods an object of class is required.

For example:

```
ViewController *controller = [ViewController alloc] init];
[controller openAccount];
```

**Point to be note here**

You have written `-viewDidLoad()` method, So `ViewController` class must be extend with `UIViewController` class otherwise it will gives you an error.

Comment: A view controller is not a container for a view, it is a manager (ie, "controller") for a view.

Comment: This Answer is Really Appreciated Thanks KAMPAI And @Hot +1 for this answer and perfect suggestion of Hot

Comment: Not quite. A "Class" is rather a _definition_ of things, not the things itself.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper Yes, I have not written any thing says that class is a thing.

Answer (score 0):

It's a convention to name the files as `[class name].h`

And in case of categories `[class]+[category].h`

In your case the `ViewController.h` you posted is actually `ViewController.m` (which is the implementation file, not the interface, "`h`" stands for header file).

A `ViewController` class extends `UIViewController` class and you can go down the hierarchy path to the root class which is `NSObject`.

Comment: It is apparently the custom of the latest XCode versions to automatically add a "private" class extension header when creating a skeleton .c file.  The ViewController.m file above seems "perfectly normal" in this regard, except for the fact that it's named "ViewController.h".